# update sql intarray

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table

```
table list(
   lst intarray,
   owner integer);
 table files(
   file_id integer,
   uid integer
  );
```

For each `owner` I want to place all `file_id`s with corresponing `uid` into `lst`.  I've tried

```
  update list 
  set lst = lst || file_id 
  FROM files
  WHERE uid = owner ;
```

The `intarray`s are all initialized to empty arrays.  What seems to happen is that I add a single element to the list on each execution.  I expect (and want) them to be added all at once.

Clearly, I am confused.  Can someone help to clarify?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no `intarray` data type in Postgres.

Comment: @LenB I'm guessing it does something more than just `CREATE DOMAIN intarray AS int[]`? Searching turned up [this module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/intarray.html) but there's no mention of it adding a type alias, all the examples just use the standard `int[]` notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update statement (logically speaking) first finds all rows that match your `WHERE` condition, then for each of those rows, applies the actions in the `SET` clause. The join semantics provided by the `FROM` clause don't change this, so each row is only ever updated once.

What you can do instead is calculate the new value of the list in a single query, using the `array_agg` aggregate function:

```
SELECT
  uid,
  array_agg(file_id)
FROM
  files
GROUP BY
  uid;
```

Since we now have one row for each owner, we can use this in our `UPDATE` statement; the simplest way would be to put it in a sub-query:

```
UPDATE list
  SET lst = subquery.calculated_list
FROM
(
  SELECT
      uid,
      array_agg(file_id) as calculated_list
  FROM
      files
  GROUP BY
      uid
) AS subquery
WHERE
  subquery.uid = owner;
```

I've created [a SQLFiddle demo of the above](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/65f9e6/5).

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
UPDATE list
   SET list.lst = list.lst OR files.file_id
   FROM list  INNER JOIN  files ON list.owner = files.uid
```

Comment: `||` doesn't mean the same thing as `OR` - for some reason, it's the SQL standard operator for "concatenate strings", which Postgres extends to similar actions such as "append to array".

Comment: Also, the self-join is explicitly not needed in Postgres's version of the `UPDATE ... FROM` syntax; as written, this would effectively perform `list CROSS JOIN list` because you've mentioned the table twice without any join condition.